# how map data from Firestore with nested struct in database with swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

Just how to read data from Firestore with nested struct in DB

with no nested struct it's ok.

```
struct Info {
    let placeOfBirth: String
    let year: String
}

struct User {
    var userName: String
    var email: String?
    var info: Info
    init?(data: [String: Any]) {
        guard let userName = data["userName"] as? String,
        let info =    //???? I don't know how coding
        else {return nil}
        self.userName = userName
        self.email = data["email"] as? String
        self.info = ?????
    }
}

// here I'd like to retrieve user.info...
```

How should be the code in swift to retrieve info.placeOfBirdh or info.year?
ty

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I am stuck and completely lost as to how to attach the collection to the nested struct.